# AWS social login issue on Android 14

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, google-signin, android-14

I am using AWS cognito social login to implement Google and Facebook login in my app.
Everything well but on Android 14, the sign in page opens momentarily and then returns to the app login page with no action.
Does anyone know how to fix it?

I tried to update my AWS SDK and Android target API level to latest version but not work.
The logcat showed that "com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.cognitoauth.exceptions.AuthNavigationException: user cancelled...".